# Why the Apache is not starting on XAMPP

Tags: php, apache, xampp

Until yesterday everything was fine to my localhost, but starting yesterday, localhost is not opening. It's saying "Unable to connect".

I tried number of times to start the `Apache` on `XAMPP`, but it is saying message that busy. The port 80 is busy, I hope.

I have tried every possible way to free the port 80. For example, Disabled option that "Use port 80" in `Skype` and `Teamviewer`. I don't know which program is using the Port 80.

How can I determine that which program is using the Port 80 and then stop it permanently and use port 80 as my localhost?

Comment: Even I have tried to re-install XAMPP 3 times, and restarted my computer for the same 3 times, but it did not solve my problem.

Comment: please check skype, teamviewer if you have.

Comment: What operating system are you on?

Comment: Windows XP-SP3 is my OS. I have checked and unchecked skype and team viewer options that uses port 80.

Comment: Try netstat http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281336

Comment: Hi Ben, I tried to see the stats also, but no port is there by :80 in last

Comment: Hi. For testting, I enabled Team viewer port 80, and it was easily loading on localhost with message that "Teamviewer is using port 80". ANd even I can see that in 'cmd' in Windows XP-SP3 with command "netstat -o -n -a | findstr 0.0:80", that the output is "netstat -o -n -a | findstr 0.0:80". But when I am freeing the port 80 from team viewer neither apache gets started from XAMPP control panel nor the command "netstat -o -n -a | findstr 0.0:80" returns anything.

Comment: Have you tried running xampp as an admin? It could be something as simple as a Windows Update patch resetting your firewall exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted each and every file of XAMPP, and reinstalled the new version. Now it is working for me.

Comment: Ha ha.... This is not exact solution.

Answer (score 5):

Have you messed up with `httpd.conf` or `php.ini`?

If not and it happened by itself, you might have to try this: **Read Very Carefully**

- Go to `c:/xammp/htdocs/` folder, grab everything you need (all sites you need), and backup tn some map on your desktop.
- Do the same with `c:/xammp/mysql/data` folder too. Get all databases you need and backup those too in some `mysql folder` on desktop.
- **SAVE** that backup on DVD, CD , or maybe even a external HDD if you have one. Now you have your work saved.

After you did it, shutdown your PC for **20** seconds.

Turn your PC on, and:

- Uninstall the whole `xammp`. Erase all of the folders and other files.
- After you're done, shut down your PC again for **20** seconds.

Turn your PC on, *again*, and:

- Download the latest `xammp 1.7.1` and install
- Start `xammp` **IT MUST BE RUNNING!**

**P.S.:** My guess is that some of file may be corrupt. If that isn't going to help, my second guess is that you HDD is on fire.

So you might have to:

- Go to a store and buy new HDD
- Install it
- Set in BIOS command for new disk to be 1st boot
- Install fresh copy of WinXP
- Install `Xammp`
- When is up and running, go to backup, and move sites (backup) to htdocs folder, and `mysql/data` to the same one in `Xampps`.

**You will have everything like before.**

At the end, use that new HDD for localhost exclusively (if youre doing important things), old HDD for playing around via Internet and stuff.

Comment: Haha. Thanks for your help. I did another way. I deleted every file and then reinstalled. Now it works.

Answer (score 1):

**On Linux (Run this as *root*):**

```
netstat -taunp | grep LISTEN
```

Then you can see what process name running on what port.

**On Windows:** (I used Windows XP and I don't know about compatibitlity)

```
netstat -ao | find /i "listening"
```

You can see process ID on rightmost column. Press `Ctrl+Alt+Del` to show Task Manager, go to Process tab, open menu `View > Select Column`, show process identifier. Then find matching process name on that tab.

Comment: This page says, unable to connect to firefox

Comment: -1: Your assumption that http://127.0.0.1 will respond with a web page is invalid - not everything that could be using port 80 would necessarily respond to an http request. +1 for the linux comand balances it out to naught.

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed php on your `c:` drive, change port number *80* to *81* in `C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf`

```
#Listen 0.0.0.0:81
#Listen [::]:81
Listen 81
```

Comment: Not sure why you're suggesting to change to port 81 since he made it pretty clear he wanted to find what process was currently running on port 80 so he could kill it and run his application on port 80.

Comment: @Gromer It is worth a shot. How do you know if Mohan Sinfh wants to use port 80 or just find a fix so it will run?