# PHP wont work in apache or iis

Tags: php, mysql, apache, iis-7

I have spent two weeks trying to get PHP installed, I want t use it to interface to MYSQL.

I first installed MYSQL and got that running perfectly OK and created a small database to record information about my family tree.

I then installed PHP manually and took some sample code from a tutorial to display Hello World, I could not get the PHP element to work, I inserted some HTML code at various points in the file, all of which displayed as expected, I also inserted a chunk of javascript to display time and date, that also worked fine, but the PHP code not even giving an error message still would not display hello world.I then installed XAMPP, but did not include MYSQL as it was already running perfectly well. , but when I came to start XAMPP control panel Apache started fine but it did not recognise that MYSQL was already installed, and I could find no way of telling it where MYSQL was installed. So I uninstalled XAMPP and MYSQL and (I think) PHP and then reinstalled XAMPP selecting all the options.

This time Apache will not start on some occasions not giving any error on others giving the following error:

> Error: 
>   Apache shutdown unexpectedly. 12:19:11
>       [Apache]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,          12:19:11  
> [Apache]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method. 12:19:11  
>       [Apache]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check 12:19:11  
>       [Apache]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues 12:19:11
>       [Apache]        Attempting to start MySQL app... 12:19:39
>       [mysql]     Status change detected: running.

I have also installed XAMPP without having MYSQL previously on a laptop apache runs on this OK put still does not display hello world. 
I have each time checked the W3SVC service and stopped it where necessary. 
I am completely stuck as of now and have no idea how to proceed. I am retired 5 years, before that I worked 45 years in IT and am proficient in SQL and understand the documentation on PHP reasonably well, everything on the internet indicates put  echo "Hello World" between tags  and it should just happen, any help would be appreciated, all I really need is to get PHP running.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9962300/why-the-apache-is-not-starting-on-xampp would you check this first?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Press **Window + R**, type: `services.msc`

Find **World Wide Web Publishing Service** and Stop it !